# Текст с эффектом волны путем увеличения букв на 30% у ссылок

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  display: block;
  background-color: #2864aa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu__item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__link {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 20px 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center
}

.menu__link {
  transition: background-color .1s linear;
}

.menu__link:hover {
  background-color: #0a87ad;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#">МЕНЮ</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#">МЕНЮ</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#">МЕНЮ</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#">МЕНЮ</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Уже пробовали какие-нибудь варианты, что-то не получилось?

Comment: Да пробовал, оно в принципе работает, но оно не совсем устраивает, я бы хотел решение полегче и попроще

Comment: Ну что, не получилось?

Answer (score 1):

Когда-то делал [печатающийся текст](https://codepen.io/UModeL/pen/BaRZxOq) в виде "мексиканской волны" - возможно, после небольшой доработки, и здесь применить:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.menu__link').forEach(function(link) {
  let text = [...link.textContent];
  link.textContent = '';
  text.forEach((el, i) => {
    link.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<span style="
      animation-duration: ${1 / (link.dataset.speed || 1)}s;
      animation-delay: ${i * ((1 / (link.dataset.speed || 1)) / text.length)}s;
      animation-iteration-count: ${link.dataset.loop || 'infinite'};
    ">${el}</span>`);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */

article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
}

body {
  line-height: 1;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: max-content;
  background-color: #2864aa;
}

.menu__item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu__link {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.menu__link {
  transition: background-color .1s linear;
}

.menu__link:hover {
  background-color: #0a87ad;
}

.menu__link>span {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.menu__link:hover>span {
  animation: wave ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes wave {
  50% {
    transform: scale(1.3);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#" data-speed=".25">Скорость ÷4 Повторов: ∞</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#" data-speed="1" data-loop="">Скорость ×1 Повторов: ∞</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#" data-speed="2" data-loop="">Скорость ×2 Повторов: ∞</a>
  </li>
  <li class="menu__item">
    <a class="menu__link" href="#" data-speed="1" data-loop="2">Скорость ×1 Повторов: 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```